# Dialog is not a constructor ui5

Tags: sapui5, sap-web-ide

I get an error while using an reusing a dialog in sapui5:

> Dialog is not a constructor

I want to create a dialog fragment. dialog.js contains all functions and after that make it global in the component.js

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/base/Object"
], function (Object) {
    "use strict";

    return Object.extend("tmp.Zprojetyousra.controller.Dialog", {
        constructor : function (oView) {
            this._oView = oView;    
        },
        open : function () {
            var oView = this._oView;
            var oDialog = oView.byId("dialog");
            // create dialog lazily
            if (!oDialog) {
                var oFragmentController = {
                    onCloseDialog : function () {
                        oDialog.close();
                    }
                };
                // create dialog via fragment factory
                oDialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment(oView.getId(), "tmp.Zprojetyousra.view.Dialog", oFragmentController);
                // connect dialog to the root view of this component (models, lifecycle)
                oView.addDependent(oDialog);
            }
            oDialog.open();
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<core:FragmentDefinition
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
    <Dialog
        id="dialog"
        title="Hello dialogs}">
        <content>
            <core:Icon
                src="sap-icon://hello-world"
                size="8rem"
                class="sapUiMediumMargin"/>
        </content>
        <beginButton>
            <Button
                text="{i18n>dialogCloseButtonText}"
                press="onCloseDialog"/>
        </beginButton>
    </Dialog>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

JS:

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/UIComponent",
/*    "tmp/Zprojetyoussra/model/models",  peut influencer sur le code                         */
    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",

    "tmp/Zprojetyoussra/controller/Dialog"    ,
    "sap/ui/Device"
     /// device toujours doit etre a la fin des dependecies
], function (UIComponent, JSONModel, Device, Dialog) {
    "use strict";

    return UIComponent.extend("tmp.Zprojetyoussra.Component", {
        metadata: {
    //        rootView: "tmp.Zprojetyoussra.view.tesstview"
            manifest: "json"
        },
        init: function () {
            // call the base component's init function
            UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);

            // set data model
            var oData = {
                recipient : {
                    name : "World"
                }
            };
            // without this.getview
            var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(oData);
            this.setModel(oModel);
            // set i18n model
            var i18nModel = new sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel({
                bundleName : "tmp.Zprojetyoussra.i18n.i18n"
            });
            this.setModel(i18nModel, "i18n");

            /* eslint-disable no-alert */
            // debug code to show an alert for missing destination or CORS issues in the tutorial (see step 26 for details)
            this.getModel("invoice").attachEventOnce("metadataFailed", function(oEvent) {
                alert("Request to the OData remote service failed.\nRead the Walkthrough Tutorial Step 26 to understand why you don't see any data here.");
            });
            // set device model
            var oDeviceModel = new JSONModel(Device);
            oDeviceModel.setDefaultBindingMode("OneWay");
            this.setModel(oDeviceModel, "device");
            this._dialog= new Dialog();
            // create the views based on the url/hash
            this.getRouter().initialize();
        }   
    });
});
```

Error:

[image: img]

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: Dialog is not a constructor " this is the error message

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a wrong order of your imports in the controller define section. In the array you have:

```
UIComponent, JSONModel, Dialog, Device
```

but in the function definition below you have:

```
UIComponent, JSONModel, Device, Dialog
```

So the Dialog variable holds Device namespace which doesn't have a controller.

Answer (score 0):

As @vasek said put your import in the right order use this syntax in your js file :

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/UIComponent",
    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
    "tmp/Zprojetyoussra/controller/Dialog"    ,
    "sap/ui/Device"
], function (UIComponent, JSONModel, Dialog, Device) {
    "use strict";

    return UIComponent.extend("tmp.Zprojetyoussra.Component", {
        metadata: {
    //        rootView: "tmp.Zprojetyoussra.view.tesstview"
            manifest: "json"
        },
```